# JS: Calling a function from a button

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I am in the process of learning pure JavaScript. My question is very basic and I hope someone would be kind in pointing me to the right direction. In a canvas drawing exercise I am using the following function:

```
drawingTools.pencil = function () {
    document.getElementById("activeTool").value = "Pencil";

    this.mousedown = function (evt) {
        isDrawing = true;
        startX = getendY(tmp_canvas, evt);

    };
    this.mousemove = function (evt) {
        compositeDraw()
        endY = getendY(tmp_canvas, evt);

        if (isDrawing) {
            tmp_context.beginPath();
            tmp_context.moveTo(startX.x, startX.y);
            tmp_context.lineTo(endY.x, endY.y);
            tmp_context.lineJoin = 'round';
            tmp_context.lineCap = "round";
            tmp_context.stroke();
            tmp_context.strokeStyle = defaultLineColor;
            tmp_context.lineWidth = defaultLineThickness;
        }
        startX = endY;
    };
    this.mouseup = function (evt) {
        isDrawing = false;
        drawtmp_contextOncanvas();
    }
};
```

This function works fine using the following line:

```
pencil.addEventListener('click', this.changeDrawingTool, false);
```

When I try to call the `drawingTools.pencil` function using a button icon like so:

```
 document.getElementById("iconPencil").addEventListener('click', drawingTools.pencil, false);
```

The above function is not triggered.

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/pgyu7/

Comment: can you share your jsfiddle or jsbin link

Comment: `changeDrawingTool` is the global method? Can you run it by `window.changeDrawingTool`? `pencil` variable points to what?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is the jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/pgyu7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second option

```
 document.getElementById("iconPencil").addEventListener('click', drawingTools.pencil, false);
```

`this` points to `#iconPencil` element. This element doesn't implement methods like `mousedown`, `mousemove`

To avoid missing `this` you can use **bind**

```
document.getElementById("iconPencil").addEventListener('click', drawingTools.pencil.bind(pencil), false);
```

Comment: Are you sure `drawingTools` is the canvas he's trying to draw in? Look at what the `this` in that method does: `this.onmousemove` etc. I think he needs to bind it to his canvas.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately the suggested solution did not work for me. I will edit the above question with the complete source code.

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof Safjanowski for pointing me to the bind direction:    `document.getElementById("iconPencil").addEventListener('click', changeDrawingTool.bind(pencil), false);`   and the code worked just fine.